# Matlab show two fig files in one plot

Tags: matlab

I am trying to show two fig. files in one plot but it seems harder then expected. How can this be achieved?

Lets say I have two figs.

```
fig1 = openfig("someFig1.fig");
fig2 = openfig("someFig2.fig");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to display them in the same plot, you can use [copyobj](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/copyobj.html):

```
x = linspace(0,10);
y1 = sin(x);
plot(x,y1)
savefig('test.fig')

y2 = cos(x);
plot(x, y2)
savefig('test2.fig')

fig1 = openfig("test.fig");
fig2 = openfig("test2.fig");

figure
h=subplot(1,1,1);   %define subplot of 1x1

%copyobj of each figure on h subplot
copyobj(allchild(get(fig1,'CurrentAxes')),h) 
copyobj(allchild(get(fig2,'CurrentAxes')),h)
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you but I am getting error
`Error occurred while moving node between canvases.

Error in main (line 88)
ax1.Parent=t;`

Also is possible to show them in one plot like in one tile?

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't understand well your question. I edited the answer